# Typing from Rightside of a textbox

Tags: asp.net

I want to enter a text in textbox in reverse. i.e if I want to type 'Stackoverflow', I will type in this order 'wolfrevokcats' so that the text starts from right of textbox and it displays 'Stackoverflow'. I don't want to align the text by using `text-align:right`.

I will type in reverse order from right side of textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css on your textbox

```
 { direction:rtl;}
```

Suppose you have a text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="ltor"></asp:TextBox>
```

the css class should be as follows

```
.ltor {direction:rtl;}
```

Comment: But if i give masking like this ___.__ .It displays like this __.___ but i want like this ___.__

Comment: I want like maskmoney input.maskmoney,js works well for integers.but i want the same for other datatypes

Answer (score 0):

```
function rtl(element)
{   
    if(element.setSelectionRange){
        element.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    }
}

<input type="text" name="textbox" style="direction:RTL;" onkeyup="rtl(this);"/>
```